# Sending email using outlook smtp from asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried sending email through my asp.net mvc application using the following code:

```
public ActionResult ResetPassword()
    {
        if (Session["id"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
        }
        bool status = false;

        B4URepository dalObj = new B4URepository();
        var customer = dalObj.GetCustomerDetails(Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]));
        string email = customer.EmailId;
        string name = customer.Name;

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(email, name));
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("sender-outlook-email");
        //mailMessage.Sender = new MailAddress("sender-outlook-email", "sender-name");
        mailMessage.Subject = "<h3>Password reset</h3>";
        mailMessage.Body = "Hello";
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

        try
        {
            smtp.Send(mailMessage);
            status = true;
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            status = false;
        }
        if (status)
            return View("Success");
        else
            return View("Error");
    }
```

and the following settings in Web.config:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="sender-outlook-email">
    <network host="smtp-mail.outlook.com"
             port="587"
             userName="sender-outlook-email"
             password="sender-password"
             enableSsl="true"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
<!--<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="Z:\MailDump"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>-->
```

Using the commented code i.e. the mail settings I checked if the email is atleast being created successfully and found it gets created and stored in the specified directory.

But on trying to send mail using the above code it gives an exception on the line "smtp.Send(mailMessage)" :

```
    [SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 65.55.163.152:587]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +185
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) +506

[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
   System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6) +6525976
   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) +302
   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) +23
   System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) +328
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) +141
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) +236
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() +45
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1574

[SmtpException: Failure sending mail.]
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1916
   B4UMVC.Controllers.CustomerController.ResetPassword() in C:\Users\zainab.TRN\Desktop\B4USol_integrated\B4USol_new2\B4USol\B4UMVC\Controllers\CustomerController.cs:755
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9744373
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `client name` and `port number`, and then set the `UseDefaultCredentials` to false, if you're using some other credential other than yours(the loggedin credentials)

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com");
client.Port = 587;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

This should work.